# Adjust some CSS when Twitter bootsrap Dropdown Nav menu is finished it's operation

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want use JS to make some adjustments to the CSS when the navigation dropdown in Twitter Bootsrap has finished it's operation. ( ie when it's fully down, fully up, or one of the sub menu operations finishes ).

What I want to do is not particularly relevant I think, but it's basically just to do with changing the height of a background div to match the height of the dropdown.

I have looked at the bootstrap collapse jquery but it's really too complex for me to figure out. Can anyone tell me what I should be hooking into of if there's an easier way of achieving this.

Here is the relevant code:  What I want to do is to have something fire when this dropdown is fully extended

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container">

<!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
<a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</a>

<!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
<a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>

<!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
<div class="nav-collapse collapse">
<nav >
<ul class="nav">
    <li ><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">Pages</a></li>
    <li >Pages</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ><a href="">Quamquam tu hanc copiosiorem</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Quamquam tu hanc copiosiorem</a></li>
        <li ><a href="">Quamquam tu hanc copiosiorem</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show an example code and explain what you wanna achieve?

Comment: A good technical question but hard to answer without any links/code snippets/examples/etc.

Comment: not really, it's the standard code from Twitter bootstrap but I'll include that above if you want. I dont understand what your mean by what I want to achieve, it's 100% discernable from the question, what do you mean exactly

Comment: please hold the downvotes i'm copying the code right now !

Comment: @byronyasgur If you want to avoid downvotes / general low interest, skim through [the checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) before posting.

Comment: @millimoose thanks yes i tend to do as much prep as possible but having used stack exchange for a couple of years I still find it a very strange, unpredicable and wonderfully random place ;-)  It is however a fantastic resource despite how it makes me want to trash my computer at times. I find the downvotes are as much to do with the time of day as anything

Comment: There aren't any downvotes for your question! ;)

Comment: I think it's 4 downvotes and 4 up so zero but I could be wrong

Comment: @byronyasgur Click on the number...it shows you the number of upvotes and downvotes

Comment: @byronyasgur The Bootstrap documentation shows that the plugin fires events called `shown` and `hidden`, wouldn't those do?

Comment: @ian Not terribly interested at the downvote history moment but thanks for the tip

Comment: @millimoose it might, how would I go about using those. Do you want to make an answer with it in it

Comment: @byronyasgur You said "I think it's 4 downvotes and 4 up so zero but I could be wrong"...that sounds like you're "interested at the downvote history". Just trying to clear it up since you assumed you got downvotes but didn't...

Comment: @byronyasgur The [docs go over that](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse). Look for the example after Events.

Comment: @millimoose I will, thanks for the pointer

Comment: @Ian ... not sure why you think I didn't get downvotes it was at minus 2 or 3 or more at one stage anyway  ... not a problem though ... thanks again for tip again

Comment: @millimoose tried out your idea. I got it working but it wont work for submenus. That documentation page doesn't show any events for dropdown. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @byronyasgur Since it's not animated, Bootstrap doesn't really provide callbacks for dropdowns. My approach would be to either modify Bootstrap to provide the events you need - look at the functions `clearMenus()` and `toggle()` in dropdown.js. (The code isn't really that complicated.) Or, if you only need to detect that an dropdown has finished activating, you might be able to make do with just monkeypatching `Dropdown.prototype.toggle()` with a wrapper that triggers an event after the original function finishes.

Comment: @millimoose what i ended up doing was combining those events that you pointed me to with a piece of anAgent's code below ... then I also had to put a timeout on it .. not exactly the most elegant but works for me ... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look at the boostrap.js file under the "**DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION**" section of the code.

In looking at the code, something like this should get you started.

```
$("a.dropdown-toggle").on('click.dropdown.data-api','', function(r) { 
      console.log(r) 
})
```

From the code in bootstrap.js, this will fire when the drop down is hidden.

```
$('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () { 
   ///... 
})
```

If you're looking for the collapse stuff, then you'll want to look at the "**COLLAPSIBLE DATA-API**" selection.

Comment: You don't need all those namespaces in your own code. `.on('click', ...)` should be fine.